# Regular expression to extract a sentence that has the frequecny of word ony twice?

Tags: regex

```
aardvark is an animal with aardvark
aardvark is an animal with aardvark along with another aardvark
aardvark is an animal with an elephant that loves an aardvark that lives in downtown
```

or

```
aardvark is an animal with aardvark. aardvark is an animal with aardvark along with another aardvark. aardvark is an animal with an elephant that loves an aardvark that lives in downtown
```

This is the text where I have to extract only that sentence that has `aardvark` occurring only twice.

I tried this expression `((.*?)(aardvark)(.*?)(aardvark)(.*?)[\.\n])` and `(.*\baardvark\b.*){2}` but I am getting all sentences as answers.

How should I proceed with it ?

Comment: It's generally a LOT easier to just use the logic of a programming language here. Use one RegEx to identify sentences, then another regex to see if any sentence has two occurrences of the string.

Comment: I understand what you mean, so suppose I ignore the sentence thing ... then the regular expressions that I have mentioned in the post are matching two or more than two `aardvark`s. How do I do that ?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey The second line is very confusing, it begins with `ardvark` and I was testing and testing until I saw a missing `a` ~_~

Comment: @AnimeshPandey: use `preg_match_all('/\baardvark\b/', $sentence)` and then check if the number of matches equals 2.

Comment: Helps to know what programming language you will use the regular expressions from. Most will provide a function or operator that will either return a value for number of matches in a string or set that value to a special global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(((?!\baardvark\b)\b\w+\b\s+)*?\baardvark\b\s*((?!\baardvark\b)\b\w+\b\s+)*?){2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for sentences with a simple (static) word, you don't need to use regular expressions at all.

```
$words = explode(' ', $sentence); # or preg_split, if you want to split on space, tab, hyphen, etc.
$counts = array_count_values($words);
if($count['aardvark'] == 2) {
  // found!
} else {
  // not interested
}
```

Comment: I very well understand this PHP code but I require only a regular expression !

Comment: In fact there is a special function dedicated for this [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) :)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: yep, but then you cannot split the sentence with a regular expression. `substr_count` will also count `preaardvarkest`, which is not a complete word.

Comment: @knittl you got me there :p

Comment: @AnimeshPandey: why do you want to use a regular expression if you can do it with 3 lines of code?

Comment: hm. Why did I assume you were using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use regular expressions:

```
<?php

$data = 'aardvark aardvark aardvark aardvark
aardvark is an animal with aardvark
aardvark is an animal with aardvark along with another aardvark
aardvark is an animal with an elephant that loves an aardvark that lives in downtown';

preg_match_all("@(^|[\.\n])((?:(?!aardvark).)*(aardvark)(?:(?!aardvark).)*(aardvark)(?:(?!aardvark).)*)([\.\n]|$)@sU", ($data), $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $match)
    echo $match[2] . '<br />';
```

Comment: Yeah, it just filters sentences with less than 2 times 'aardvark'. I don't know a way to have 'aardvark' not in the (.*) in regex.

Comment: To assert an arbitrary sequence does not form some word `(?:(?!word).)*`. I wouldn't do this, though. There should be better way to solve this rather than regex (although I can write a regex solution for this).

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks, I updated my answer, it works now on my local server, but NOT on http://www.regex101.com

Comment: My own solution, using `.` as delimiter for a sentence: http://www.regex101.com/r/mG4tR1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<pre>
<?php
$subject = <<<LOD
aardvark is an animal with aardvark
aardvark is an animal with aardvark along with another aardvark
aardvark is an animal with an elephant that loves an aardvark that lives in downtown
LOD;

$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
(?(DEFINE) # the word
    (?<tw> \b aardvark \b ) )

(?(DEFINE) # other word
    (?<ow> \b (?!\g<tw>)[a-z]++ \b ) )

(?(DEFINE) # not a word 
    (?<nw>[^a-z]++) )

(?(DEFINE) # not the word
    (?<ntw> (?> \g<ow> | \g<nw> )++ ) )

# pattern :    
    ^ \g<ntw>? \g<tw> \g<ntw> \g<tw> \g<ntw>? $ 
~xim
LOD;
/* a more condensed version */
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
    ^ (?<ntw> (?> \b(?!\g<tw>)[a-z]++\b | [^a-z]++ )++ )?
      (?<tw> \b aardvark \b )
      \g<ntw> \g<tw> \g<ntw>? $
~xim
LOD;

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

notice that you can replace the "ow" group by `(?<ow> \b (?> [b-z] | (?!\g<tw>)a ) [a-z]*+ \b ) )` for more performance, but keep in mind that you must change the letter and the first class for a word that does not begin with the letter a. 
example for "koala":

```
(?<ow> \b (?> [a-jl-z] | (?!\g<tw>)k ) [a-z]*+ \b ) )
```